# Can someone downvote me over a reason they are wrong on, and the downvote stands?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316179/why-cant-my-friend-push-to-github#) and it was downvoted for lack of command line but I used a plugin for eclipse and never used command line as implied by my tags but the downvote stands.

Comment: It was downvoted for more than that.

Comment: not acording to the comment

Comment: You have 2 downvotes and three close votes. And I highly expect that will now increase given the exposure provided by this post. Your question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: [Meta-Effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Answer (score 13):

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question. *If* you're able to produce a clear, answerable question (that doesn't rely on comments to flesh it out) *and* the voters revisit it, they'll then be able to change their vote.

If you don't edit to clarify, you've given no one any reason to retract their votes - and the votes are locked in anyway, so they couldn't retract them if they wanted to.

Comment: ive taken back my vote plenty of times

Comment: The lock kicks in after 5 minutes, and is released if an edit is made after that. So you can change/retract your vote within 5 minutes, or after an edit.