# What is the meta effect?

Tags: discussion, voting, meta, meta-effect

I was reading some discussions on here, and came across the term "meta effect". Can anyone explain what is meant by this? and what is the purpose?

Comment: MSE: [What is the "meta effect"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: Related: [Impose a 24 hour voting freeze on questions being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269191/456814).

Comment: The Meta effect describes a situation where, after bringing attention to one of your posts by discussing it on Meta, your post experiences additional attention, attracted from your post discussing it on Meta.

Comment: It is [an official meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/204311#204311).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The meta effect refers to the community reaction to certain posts here on Meta, in particular posts that point to another post on Stack Overflow.

This tends to be a negative effect - people who come to complain/ask about posts on Stack Overflow on Meta are essentially inviting scrutiny and review of these posts. More often than not, it means a flurry of downvotes, close votes and delete votes on a post.

The term describes this effect - that's its purpose.

Comment: Well, whether it's negative or positive depends on the observers viewpoint, and on why the post was mentioned. If it was for example mentioned to protest an incorrect closure / deletion without being inflamatory, the meta-effect won't only provide swift correction of the problem but also some upvotes.

Comment: Waiting to see a positive effect. So far my points are only tanking since I asked for help on meta. There was a flurry of harsh almost defensive feedback and a flood of dislikes on past questions. There were a few nice people also. Now am waiting to see if my points will really tank till they hit 0 or not because of the meta effect

Comment: flood of downvotes and not dislikes. but the points are tanking on my profile

Comment: Saw some positives also. To All. While its true that there was a huge downvotes to many past questions. there have also been some positives. A few people spoke nicely. One person also requested approval for some edits. This not only helped me appreciate the editing but I think they were actually helping me get some points back. That would also be meta effect.